# existence of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$= { $z \epsilon \Bbb C :|z|<1$ } .   Then there exists a holomorphic function $f:D\to \overline D$ with $f(0)=0$ with the property

a) $f'(0)={1\over 2}$

b) $|f(1/3)|={1\over 4}$

c) $f(1/3)={1\over 2}$

d) $|f'(0)|=\sec(\pi/6)$

> when $f(z)={1\over 2}z$ then $a)$ is true
>
> when $f(z)={1\over 4}$ then $b)$ is true
>
> To solve the problem do we've to take such examples?Or is there any other way?

Comment: See [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
         If $f(z)$ is holomorphic function from $D$ onto itself, where $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$ and $f(0)=0$, then $|f(z)|\le|z|$ and $|f'(z)|\le1$ for all $z\in D$, by Schwartz lemma

Comment: Then I've got b) as true and d) as false .But what about the other choices.

Comment: @Tani..(a) true by |f′(z)|≤1 and (c) false by |f(z)|≤|z|.

Comment: read my answer carefully @Tani...it is for all z∈D.

Answer (score 1):

**Another approach:**
                 You can think of a linear function f(z)=az, where |a|≤1 for all z in D  and satisfying f(0)=0. Then f '(z)=a ,|a|≤1.
You can easily see that options (3) and (4) do not satisfy the condition |a|≤1.